# Castle Windsor FirstInterface().Configure(c=> c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest)

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle

I am Looking at ProDiner Sample MVC project. I updated the Castle Windsor reference to 3 from 2.

```
public static void RegisterAllFromAssemblies(string a)
    {
        IoC.Container.Register(
            AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed(a).Pick().WithService
            .FirstInterface().Configure(c=> c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest));
    }
```

The c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest has a red squiggly saying

```
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: .FirstInterface().Configure(reg => reg.LifestylePerWebRequest()));  this seems to be compiling....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of those method calls are now marked as obsolete. This is the latest way of using the api:

```
container.Register(
    Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Classes.FromAssemblyNamed(a)
    .WithServiceFirstInterface()
    .LifestylePerWebRequest()
);
```